# c# FileStream.Lock what happens?

Tags: c#, locking, filestream

I've recently read in a book about `FileStream.Lock` to lock part or whole of a file. I understand this part however I'm confused about what happens next.

If you create a `FileStream` object, and then lock the file.

```cs
fileStream.Lock(0, fileStream.Lenght);
```

can you only use that filestream object to write to the file? Even if only part of the file is locked

```cs
fileStream.Lock(0, 2);
```

The impression I got from the book is that you can create another `FileStream` object and buffer text to be flushed, but flushing before releasing the lock causes an Exception.

Whilst the file is locked;
Can you only use the original `FileStream` to write to the file, and, is this writing restricted to the locked portion?

If there are different answers for both partial locking and full file content locking then I'd like to hear both.

I'm curious if you can create multiple filestreams on a file each with partial locks? All and any information to help make `FileStream.Lock` clear is appreciated.

Comment: The file locking happens on the OS level ("[FileStream.Lock] [p]revents *other processes* from reading from or writing to the [file]."), so *actual I/O attempts* through to the are OS what can trigger an exception. There is no direct coordination between multiple FileStream instances. Internally it's implemented with an OS call like [LockFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfile) or similar.

Comment: By other processes I think you mean other applications/threads outside the thread that created the FileStream with the lock? Are you also saying that only the instance that created the lock can write to the file and that only the locked section can be written to?

Comment: I'd "expect" it to be *per-process* (with a caveat that "most" FileStream constructors open a new file handle). From the LockFile API: "*Locking a region of a file gives [all] the threads of the locking process exclusive access to the specified region using this file handle.* If the file handle is inherited by a process created by the locking process, the child process is not granted access to the locked region. *If the locking process opens the file a second time, it cannot access the specified region through this second handle until it unlocks the region.*"

Comment: Of course, one could [create a new FileStream from an _existing_ FileStream's Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_Microsoft_Win32_SafeHandles_SafeFileHandle_System_IO_FileAccess_). In which case the *per-process* behavior should be retained as the same underlying handle is used.

Comment: So, perhaps saying "per-process *and* file handle". Child-processes, regardless of inheriting any handles are not given access via LockFile. And threads within the same process are given access, should the same handle be used. I would not be surprised if the effective behavior may be subtle different on non-Windows targets. Adding in the "..and handle.." bit to the documentation might also force some implementations out of simple face-value compliance.

Comment: I've re-read your comments over and over, googled the SafeFileHandle property of the FileStream class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.safefilehandle?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: This is what I think I understand, the operating system handles the open/close/locking/editing ect of files, the FileStream object gets a handle object which is an OS API for handling files, every time you create a new FileStream you create a new handle with that FileStream object, however you can pass the SafeFileHandler object to a new FileStream object. I'm guessing in the constructor. If that SafeFileHandler was used to create a Lock then passing it to another FileStream object means that the FileStream object can only access the locked section.

Comment: Because I have little to no experience with Threading I am still confused about what other FileStream objects with their own SafeFileHandlers can do. If they are part of the same Thread, such as the main thread, can they edit the file area's that aren't locked?

Or maybe now that I'm thinking about it, does the SafeFileHandler run on a seperate Thread/Process and it's only that thread/process that can access the file.

Trying to understand is all.

Comment: The _thread doesn't matter_ for the behavior of FileStream.Lock on Windows. Only processes and file handles - naturally, using the same FileStream instance uses the same handle; as does using a new FileStream explicitly bound to avoid same handle. (Using `lock` is likely required around many FileStream methods to avoid thread-related concurrency errors when using the _same_ `FileStream` between thread, regardless of the handle it uses; however, the file-locking itself is _per-process_, and is handled at the OS level.)

Comment: For example, the FileStream.Write API says "IOException [can be throw if] Another thread may have caused an unexpected change in the position of the operating system's file handle." This would also indicate that _all_ FileStreams performing [some subset of] operations against the same handle should be synchronized in the same process. Then it's getting into the details about what the "some subset of" operations that must be synchronized for correct program behavior. Generally, the 'safest' approach to apply `lock` consistently. Anyway.. these errors are different from [File] Lock errors.

Comment: Anyway, back above: "..every time you create a new FileStream you create a new handle with that FileStream object, however you can pass the SafeFileHandler object to a new FileStream object.." that's correct. However, a `SafeFileHandle` is simply an [sort of] *opaque value type* to pass around some information used in the underlying implementation (think of it as a numeric type that could be "any value"; some of these instances may share the same value, and to C# code itself the actual value itself is irrelevant). Since it's only a value, `SafeFileHandle` doesn't "run" on any thread.